# What is meant by the symbol “$\equiv$” in this context?

Tags: geometry, notation

[image: diagram referred to by derivation]
[image: mathematical derivation with confusing statement highlighted]

See the highlighted text in the 2nd photo, where it says
$$
    \triangle OAC \equiv \triangle OC'A'
$$
What is meant by the symbol “$\equiv$”?

Comment: $\cong$ for [Congruent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(geometry)#Congruence_of_triangles).

Comment: The sign $\equiv$ means "is equivalent" or "is congruent to"

Comment: What does it have to do with Statistics? What you highlighted ($\color{red}\equiv$) means the triangles are congruent.

Comment: I've heavily edited the post to clarify what I believe is your question—please let me know if I missed something.

Comment: Matthew, nice edit. I liked most the part how you merged the two pics. I'll use this way in future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol $\equiv$ has different meanings in different contexts, but it usually refers to an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) distinct from actual equality.

In this context of plane Euclidean geometry, it seems the author is using it for the [congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(geometry)#Congruence_of_triangles) relation on polygons.